# Game of Life Problems in C

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array, heap-memory, conways-game-of-life

Im creating the Game of Life Program which I created a working copy of but im having issues making it so that the user can enter the grid's x and y(rows and columns) when I try alter my code to do it it gets messy and causes alot of errors. Also im trying to use `malloc()` and `free()` to start using heaps and im having no luck. The code below is just a working hard coded solution. (I also commented out the test data and user input part). Thank you in advance for any help given.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define HEIGHT 12
#define WIDTH 12
#define LIFE_YES 'X'
#define LIFE_NO 'O'

typedef int TableType[HEIGHT][WIDTH];

void printTable(TableType table) {
    int height, width;

        for (height = 0; height < HEIGHT; height++) {
            for (width = 0; width < WIDTH; width++) {
                    if (table[height][width] == LIFE_YES) {
                        printf("X");
                    } 
            else {
                        printf("-");
                    }
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
        printf("\n");
}

void clearTable(TableType table) {
    int height, width;

        for (height = 0; height < HEIGHT; height++) {
            for (width = 0; width < WIDTH; width++) {
                    table[height][width] = LIFE_NO;
            }
        }
}

void askUser(TableType tableA) {
    int i;
        int n;
        int height, width;

        printf("Enter the amount of initial organisms: ");
        scanf("%d", &n);

        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            printf("Enter dimensions (x y) where organism %d will live: ", i + 1);
            scanf("%d %d", &height, &width);

            tableA[height][width] = LIFE_YES;
        }

        printTable(tableA);
        printf("Generation 0");
}

int getNeighborValue(TableType table, int row, int col) {
        if (row < 0 || row >= HEIGHT || col < 0 || col >= WIDTH || table[row][col] != LIFE_YES ) {
            return 0;
        } 
    else {
            return 1;
        }
}

int getNeighborCount(TableType table, int row, int col) {
        int neighbor = 0;

        neighbor += getNeighborValue(table, row - 1, col - 1);
        neighbor += getNeighborValue(table, row - 1, col);
        neighbor += getNeighborValue(table, row - 1, col + 1);
        neighbor += getNeighborValue(table, row, col - 1);
        neighbor += getNeighborValue(table, row, col + 1);
        neighbor += getNeighborValue(table, row + 1, col - 1);
        neighbor += getNeighborValue(table, row + 1, col);
        neighbor += getNeighborValue(table, row + 1, col + 1);

        return neighbor;
}

void calculate(TableType tableA) {
        TableType tableB;
        int neighbor, height, width;

        for (height = 0; height < HEIGHT; height++) {
            for (width = 0; width < WIDTH; width++) {
                    neighbor = getNeighborCount(tableA, height, width);
                    if (neighbor==3) {
                        tableB[height][width] = LIFE_YES;
                    } 
            else if (neighbor == 2 && tableA[height][width] == LIFE_YES) {
                        tableB[height][width] = LIFE_YES;
                    } 
            else {
                        tableB[height][width] = LIFE_NO;
                    }
            }
        }

        for (height = 0; height < HEIGHT; height++) {
            for (width = 0; width < WIDTH; width++) {
                    tableA[height][width] = tableB[height][width];
            }
    }
}

/* test data
void loadTestData(TableType table) {
        table[3][4] = LIFE_YES;
        table[3][5] = LIFE_YES;
        table[3][6] = LIFE_YES;

        table[10][4] = LIFE_YES;
        table[10][5] = LIFE_YES;
        table[10][6] = LIFE_YES;
        table[11][6] = LIFE_YES;
        table[12][5] = LIFE_YES;
}
*/

int main(void) {
        TableType table;
        char end;
        int generation = 0;

        clearTable(table);
        /*askUser(table);*/
        /*loadTestData(table);*/
        printTable(table);

        while (end != 'q') {
            calculate(table);
            printTable(table);
            printf("Generation %d\n", ++generation);
            printf("Press q to quit or 1 to continue: ");
            scanf(" %c", &end);
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Output for first instance of Test Data: X's on [3][4], [3][5], [3][6].

```
------------
------------
------------
----XXX-----
------------
------------
------------
------------
------------
------------
------------
------------
```

Update:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define LIFE_YES 'X'
#define LIFE_NO 'O'

extern int HEIGHT, WIDTH;
typedef int **TableType;

void printTable(TableType table) {
    int height, width;

        for (height = 0; height < HEIGHT; height++) {
            for (width = 0; width < WIDTH; width++) {
                    if (table[height][width] == LIFE_YES) {
                        printf("X");
                    } 
            else {
                        printf("-");
                    }
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
        printf("\n");
}

void clearTable(TableType table) {
    int height, width;

        for (height = 0; height < HEIGHT; height++) {
            for (width = 0; width < WIDTH; width++) {
                    table[height][width] = LIFE_NO;
            }
        }
}

void askUser(TableType tableA) {
    int i;
        int n;
        int height, width;

        printf("Enter the amount of initial organisms: ");
        scanf("%d", &n);

        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            printf("Enter dimensions (x y) where organism %d will live: ", i + 1);
            scanf("%d %d", &height, &width);

            tableA[height][width] = LIFE_YES;
        }

        printTable(tableA);
        printf("Generation 0");
}

int getNeighborValue(TableType table, int row, int col) {
        if (row < 0 || row >= HEIGHT || col < 0 || col >= WIDTH || table[row][col] != LIFE_YES ) {
            return 0;
        } 
    else {
            return 1;
        }
}

int getNeighborCount(TableType table, int row, int col) {
        int neighbor = 0;

        neighbor += getNeighborValue(table, row - 1, col - 1);
        neighbor += getNeighborValue(table, row - 1, col);
        neighbor += getNeighborValue(table, row - 1, col + 1);
        neighbor += getNeighborValue(table, row, col - 1);
        neighbor += getNeighborValue(table, row, col + 1);
        neighbor += getNeighborValue(table, row + 1, col - 1);
        neighbor += getNeighborValue(table, row + 1, col);
        neighbor += getNeighborValue(table, row + 1, col + 1);

        return neighbor;
}

void calculate(TableType tableA) {
        TableType tableB;
        int neighbor, height, width;

        for (height = 0; height < HEIGHT; height++) {
            for (width = 0; width < WIDTH; width++) {
                    neighbor = getNeighborCount(tableA, height, width);
                    if (neighbor==3) {
                        tableB[height][width] = LIFE_YES;
                    } 
            else if (neighbor == 2 && tableA[height][width] == LIFE_YES) {
                        tableB[height][width] = LIFE_YES;
                    } 
            else {
                        tableB[height][width] = LIFE_NO;
                    }
            }
        }

        for (height = 0; height < HEIGHT; height++) {
            for (width = 0; width < WIDTH; width++) {
                    tableA[height][width] = tableB[height][width];
            }
    }
}

/* test data
void loadTestData(TableType table) {
        table[3][4] = LIFE_YES;
        table[3][5] = LIFE_YES;
        table[3][6] = LIFE_YES;

        table[10][4] = LIFE_YES;
        table[10][5] = LIFE_YES;
        table[10][6] = LIFE_YES;
        table[11][6] = LIFE_YES;
        table[12][5] = LIFE_YES;
}
*/

int main(void) {
        char end;
        int generation = 0;

        printf("Enter the amount of rows and columns you want in the grid: ");
        scanf("%i%i\n" &HEIGHT, &WIDTH);

        TableType table = malloc(HEIGHT * sizeof(int*));
        for (int i = 0; i < HEIGHT; i++) {
            table[i] = malloc(WIDTH * sizeof(int));
    }

        clearTable(table);
        /*askUser(table);*/
        /*loadTestData(table);*/
        printTable(table);

        while (end != 'q') {
            calculate(table);
            printTable(table);
            printf("Generation %d\n", ++generation);
            printf("Press q to quit or 1 to continue: ");
            scanf(" %c", &end);
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Calculate()

```
void calculate(TableType tableA) {
        TableType tableB;
        int neighbor, height, width, i;
    **tableB= malloc(HEIGHT * sizeof(int*));

    for (i = 0; i < HEIGHT; i++) {
            tableB[i] = malloc(WIDTH * sizeof(int));
    }

        for (height = 0; height < HEIGHT; height++) {
            for (width = 0; width < WIDTH; width++) {
                    neighbor = getNeighborCount(tableA, height, width);
                    if (neighbor==3) {
                        tableB[height][width] = LIFE_YES;
                    } 
            else if (neighbor == 2 && tableA[height][width] == LIFE_YES) {
                        tableB[height][width] = LIFE_YES;
                    } 
            else {
                        tableB[height][width] = LIFE_NO;
                    }
            }
        }

        for (height = 0; height < HEIGHT; height++) {
            for (width = 0; width < WIDTH; width++) {
                    tableA[height][width] = tableB[height][width];
            }
    }
    free(tableB);
}
```

Comment: "it gets messy and causes alot of errors." <- That's not really a problem description, is it?

Comment: It would be helpful if can explain what is the expected output and how close is your output. Btw, thank you for providing hte input data (loadTestData)!

Comment: I works perfectly im trying to edit to take the users specification on grid size and for how many generations they want to see. Its just since its I hard coded everything im having issues trying to un-hard code it.

Answer (score 2):

Change your type definition to:

```
typedef int **TableType;
```

and change `HEIGHT` and `WIDTH` from macros to global variables (or local variables that you pass to each function that receives the table as an argument).

After getting `HEIGHT` and `WIDTH` from the user, you can initialize the table with:

```
table = malloc(HEIGHT * sizeof(int*));
for (int i = 0; i < HEIGHT; i++) {
    table[i] = malloc(WIDTH * sizeof(int));
}
```

Comment: Would that be the only changes I need to make in order to get the grid using the users input? Also would the table ='s part go in my main method.

Comment: Yes, the table assignment goes in `main()`. I think this should be all you need to change.

Comment: I updated my code does it look fine now?

Comment: You shouldn't overwrite the original code in the question, how is anyone supposed to understand my answer if they don't see what you wrote? Please put back the original code, and add your rewrite as an UPDATE at the bottom. Anyway, does your new version work as desired?

Comment: I get a for loop initial declaration used outside of c99 mode error on the the for loop you created.

Comment: Why are you compiling in pre-C99 mode? Anyway, you can move the variable declaration out of the for loop.

Comment: Ok I have everything running but I've got alot of undefined references to `HEIGHT` and `WIDTH` should * infornt of them solve this

Comment: You shouldn't declare them `extern`.

Comment: Ok now i just have a segmentation fault so I know I need to free the malloced memory somewhere

Comment: It will be freed when the program finishes. That won't cause a segmentation fault. What line is the fault happening on?

Comment: The problem is `tableB` in `calculate()`. You never allocated space for it. You need to allocate it the same way as `tableA`. This one you need to free when it's done. Or just allocate it once in `main()`, and pass it to `calculate()` as an argument.

Comment: It happens right after I enter the `HEIGHT` and `WIDTH` in the program. When I compile I get no warnings or errors though.

Comment: Do you mean put the same declaration and for loop you made into `calculate`. Sorry for asking so many questions this is my first time using this stuff.

Comment: Yes. We changed `tableType` from an array to a pointer. Pointers don't get memory assigned to them automatically, like declaring an array does, so you need to allocate it with `malloc()`. Then when you're done you need to free everything, since this is a temporary array.

Comment: I don't plan on staying here to teach you everything you need to know about using pointers in C. You should have learned that as part of learning the language.

Comment: **tableB= malloc(HEIGHT * sizeof(int*));

     for (i = 0; i < HEIGHT; i++) {
          table[i] = malloc(WIDTH * sizeof(int));
     }

Comment: In the `for` loop it should be `tableB[i]`.

Comment: Now I only get a warning for making an int for a pointer without a cast. Also I still get a segmentation fault if I just run the code.

Comment: It should be `tableB = malloc(...)`, not `**tableB = malloc(...)`.

Comment: Ok I will try that first thing in the morning when I go back to the lab. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: It didnt solve my seg fault problem.